# Why the height of iframe in percentage is not working in my case?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a page which is 100% of the browser height.

The page has 3 `iframe`: `id_iframe_top`, `id_iframe_middle_left` and `id_iframe_middle_right`.

`id_iframe_top` is on top and has a width of 100%.

`id_iframe_middle_left` and `id_iframe_middle_right` are side by side; `id_iframe_middle_left` has a width of 30% and `id_iframe_middle_right` has a width of 70%.

This is the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="id_div_top_row">
    <iframe id="id_iframe_top" frameborder="0" src="">
    </iframe>
</div>
<div id="id_div_middle_row">
    <iframe id="id_iframe_middle_left" frameborder="0" src="">
    </iframe>
    <iframe id="id_iframe_middle_right" frameborder="0" src="">
    </iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

This is the CSS:

```
html {
    background: Green;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: White;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    left: 0;
}

iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#id_iframe_top {
    background-color: Red;
    width: 100%;
}

#id_iframe_middle_left, #id_iframe_middle_right {
    float: left;
}

#id_iframe_middle_left {
    background-color: Pink;
    width: 30%;
}

#id_iframe_middle_right {
    background-color: Yellow;
    width: 70%;
}
```

This is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srhcan/6fsqdyy3/1/

Now I am trying to set the height of each of the `iframe` in percentage. So I set height of `id_iframe_top` to 20% and the heights of `id_iframe_middle_left` and `id_iframe_middle_right` to 80% in CSS:

```
#id_iframe_top {
    background-color: Red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

#id_iframe_middle_left, #id_iframe_middle_right {
    float: left;
    height: 80%;
}
```

But there was no affect; no matter what percentage I set for height, it is not working.

Why it is not working and how can I fix it?

Comment: Height only works in Pixels Or Percentage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the height of the div that wraps the iframe so for example:

```
#id_div_top_row {
    height:80%;
}
#id_iframe_top {
    background-color: Red;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And then if you want the iframe to stretch the entire div, you set the the height of the iframe to 100% of the div

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fsqdyy3/2/)

Comment: Thanks. It also removes the white line between top iframe and bottom 2 iframes. Perfect.

Comment: It did not work on IE. I have IE 11. It worked on Chrome, Firefox and Opera but not on IE. What changes should be made so that your solution can work on IE?

Comment: IE is showing upper half of the page white and lower half of the page light blue. Then I set the `frameborder="1"` for all 4 iframes in the jsp so I can see the borders of the iframes and I can see the iframes are in upper half of the page which is white.

Comment: Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the beginning of your html page

Comment: I already have it in the beginning. This is the whole line I have: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` When I change this line to `<!DOCTYPE html>` still the same issue

Comment: That's strange cause mine shows up.. you mind sharing a JSFiddle of your current code?

Comment: It is working on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/socvbjs2/ But the same code is not working in my Web application. I create a simple web application with only 1 JSP and 1 CSS file and deploy it to JBoss 6; then run JBoss and then went to that JSP with each browser; it did not work on IE only

Comment: Since your solution is working in JSFiddle and also in Microsoft Expression Web 4, so I will accept this as answer and for Web application I will open a separate question

Comment: It's very strange.. I'm actually still trying to find a solution to this haha  And yea your best bet is probably opening up a new question to see if anyone can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Height only works in **Px (Pixels) OR pt (Points):** Height Do Not work in Percentage Unless, If the Contant of it has a height defined

Try something like this

```
#id_iframe_top {
    background-color: Red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

#id_iframe_middle_left, #id_iframe_middle_right {
    float: left;
    height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Please review your answer. Height does work when defined in percentage, as long as the element's parent has a height defined.